# Full stop as multiplication sign

Tags: notation

I have often seen, that users of this forum use "$.$" (full-stop) as a multiplication sign, e.g. $4.5=20$

I have thought, that this notation is the american style. But a user of this forum told me that this is not the case. Therefore my question is, in which country or context is this kind of notation used ?

*Remark:* I´m only interested in notation for multiplication of numbers. I´m not interested in, e.g., the notation for multiplication  of two vectors. I´m familiar with "$\cdot$"  and "$\times$" for muliplication signs.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: I think there may be some places where it is common. However, American mathematicians really do use a centered dot for multiplication, in Latex it is \cdot. So, instead of $4.5$ I would write $4 \cdot 5$ It is possible (I do not know) that some people intend \cdot but are not sure what they are doing, and type in a full-stop

Comment: $4\cdot 5$ is the best, but $4\bullet 5$ is better for short-sighted people.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $4 \bigcirc 5$

Comment: @WillJagy $4{\huge{\bigcirc}}5$

Comment: I think I've seldom seen this in books published after about 1930 or so. I've seen it in 19th-century books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of this being a common notation anywhere, especially since it can be confused with a decimal point. I think some people use it because they aren't aware that the \cdot macro exists.

Comment: Remarkably, older literature such as e.g. Whittaker & Watson's (1902) *Course in modern analysis* uses a vertically centered dot for the decimal point.

Comment: To say nothing of the Europeans who use a comma for the decimal point...!

Comment: @ZhenLin And for the thousand seperators the Europeans  and maybe others use a point instead of a comma.